# Rails - starting background process (Resque) from another process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

I have an applications that uses Resque for background processes. So I have

```
-/app/workers/dataCollector.rb
```

and in controller:

```
def new
    @my_model = MyModel.new(params[:])
    Resque.enqueue(DataCollector, @my_model.id)
end
```

I want to add another worker that at some point will get some info from dataCollector and process it.

so I tried:

```
-app/workers/dataCollector.rb
            /dataProcessor.rb
```

and had in my MyModel class:

```
def my_function
    ...
    data.each do |d|
        Resque.enqueue(DataProcessor, data)
    end
end
```

my new worker looked like:

```
class DataProcessor
  @queue = :processing_queue
  def self.perform(data)
    new_var = processingFunction(data)
    newModel.column = new_var
  end
end
```

The resulting error was “Stack level too deep”

I ran the program once locally... with

```
 bundle exec env rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
 redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

and  never get to see processing_queue in the resque web interface.

Comment: You spelt enqueue wrong.

Comment: thanks, fixed, this was not the case in original code.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is a typo.  Instead of:

```
data.each do |d|
    Resque.enqueue(DataProcessor, data)
end
```

I think you mean:

```
data.each do |d|
    Resque.enqueue(DataProcessor, d)
end
```

Then the reason you are seeing the message "Stack level too deep" is that [Resque jobs can only accept arguments that can be JSON encoded](https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/1-x-stable#persistence), and presumably `data` cannot be.